# three subplots in a grid, one equal aspect subplot with shared x and y axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to build a layout that looks like [an example from the matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html), with some modifications:

- the central axes should have an 'equal' aspect ratio but with `xlim != ylim`
- the top axes will house a color bar for the data in the central axes
- the right axes will house a `twiny()` setup

The cited example seems to hard code in the positions of the axes, when I'd like this to be done dynamically as the x and y limits in the central axes may change.

I've tried different approaches, but I'll first walk through a method with `add_sublot()`.

The central axes can be made with something like (anticipating using an `AxisDivider` to add the top axes, thus the 121):

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
fig = gcf()
ax_c = fig.add_subplot(121,aspect='equal',xlim=[0,2],ylim=[0,0.5])
draw()
```

yielding the expected results. (This is my first time using StackExchange so I don't yet have the 10 reputation to post images, or more than two links.) Fine. But when I add the add the second subplot, like:

```
ax_r = fig.add_subplot(122,sharey=ax_c,xlim=[0,4])
draw()
```

the aspect ratio is destroyed, as are the originally set x limits.

Results using a `GridSpec` seem to be identical, and there's [another implementation of the given example](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#scatter-hist-py-with-axesdivider) with `AxesDivider`, but I've determined that I cannot use an `AxesDivider` with the help of `append_axes()` as I would also like to generate a `twiny()` axes on the right, and given the way that `twiny()` and `AxesGrid` are implemented, the `twiny()` axes ends up spanning the entire figure.

```
fig.clf()
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np
ax_c = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal',xlim=[0,2],ylim=[0,0.5])
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax_c)
ax_r = divider.append_axes("right", size=1.3, pad=0.1, sharey=ax_c)
ax_rty = ax_r.twiny()
draw()
```

I presume the colorbar, the desired top axes spanning the width of the the central axes, can be implemented with the `make_axes_locatable()` method. I've also tried an `AxesGrid`, which handles the color bar nicely, but this construction is not amenable to different axis scales and didn't seem to work for the central and right axes combination.

Comment: I think you just want `adjustable='box-forced'` to make shared axes adjust their bounding box instead of the data limits.  I don't have time for a full answer right now, but try doing `plt.setp([ax_c, ax_r], adjustable='box-forced')` or adding `adjustable='box-forced'` to each call of `add_subplot` (both are equivalent).

Comment: @JoeKington This seems to make `ax_r` vertically expanded, no longer sharing the same y axis with `ax_c`. Furthermore, trying this with `adjustable='box'` gives an error `adjustable must be "datalim" for shared axes`.

Comment: I think I'm a touch confused... I thought that's what you wanted. If you want the two axes to have the same aspect ratio, you'll need to either a) set the same aspect ratio for both (e.g. `aspect='equal'`) or b) share both the x and y axes (i.e. same data limits) or c) set the extents axes how you'd like manually (i.e. don't use subplots, just specify the bounding box).

Comment: The center axes should have an equal aspect ratio, the right axes should share an yaxis with the left. It doesn't really matter how wide the right axes is. Anyway, I think I have a solution to this problem but it doesn't use as many of the higher-level helpers. It also requires me to use a backend wherein I can control the figure size, (PDF is my target anyway). I like to solve problems in generality wherever I can, but I think it would be considerably more difficult for this to work in the interactive viewport. I'll post the answer when I have it in good form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly ugly way to answer my own question, I hacked the following code from [the first example I referenced](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/scatter_hist.html). It's definitely something I'd like to handle with higher-level helpers, so other shorter/cleaner answers are welcome.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xlim = (-60.,60.)
ylim = (-110.,110.)
axes_pad = 0.02
cbar_height = 0.025
h_pad = 0.1
v_pad = 0.1

fig_w = 7.
fig_h = 6.

height = 1-axes_pad-cbar_height-2*v_pad
width = np.abs((xlim[1]-xlim[0])/(ylim[1]-ylim[0]))*height*fig_h/fig_w # ensure equal aspect

bottom_h = v_pad+height+axes_pad
left_h = h_pad+width+axes_pad

rect_c = [h_pad, v_pad, width, height]
rect_cbar = [h_pad, bottom_h, width, cbar_height]
rect_r = [left_h, v_pad, 1-axes_pad-width-2*h_pad, height]

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(fig_w,fig_h))
ax_c = plt.axes(rect_c)
ax_cbar = plt.axes(rect_cbar)
ax_r = plt.axes(rect_r)

ax_c.set_xlim(xlim)
ax_c.set_ylim(ylim)
ax_r.set_ylim(ylim)

ax_rty = ax_r.twiny()
ax_rty.set_xlim((-100,0)) # determined dynamically later
ax_r.set_xlim((0,0.5)) # determined dynamically later

plt.savefig('skeleton.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')
```